# Razor Method Chaining/Fluent does not work with line breaks

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Lets just say I have some fluent syntax in razor like this:

```
@Model.ListOfStuff.Where(x=>x.StuffProp == "Some Stuff").FirstOrDefault().SomeOtherProp
```

But lets say that was actually really long because it is a helper that builds a complex grid.  If its all on one line it works fine, but when its on more than one line it blows apart.  How can I fix this?

```
@Model.ListOfStuff.Where(x=>x.StuffProp == "Some Stuff")
.FirstOrDefault().SomeOtherProp
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having such syntax in a view is just **wrong** and I can't stress more on it. It's not the responsibility of the view to filter and fetch data. Its responsibility is to show data that has been provided by the controller. So I would strongly recommend you using a view model and perform all those selects and stuff in the controller so that in the view all you have to write is:

```
@Model.SomeStuff
```

As you can see you no longer should be worrying about any line breaks in a view.

But to answer your question the ugliness could be wrapped in parenthesis:

```
@(Model.ListOfStuff.Where(x => x.StuffProp == "Some Stuff")
.FirstOrDefault().SomeOtherProp)
```

Comment: Yah, that was a bad example really, its not what we are doing.  Its a fluent interface to build a grid and its all just concerns of the view.  Your parenthesis worked great, thanks!

Comment: Used this to compose the MvcContrib Grid pager... Nice.

Comment: And what about fluent syntax for things like UI helpers? eg: using Telerik's grid you'd get `Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.Orders)
                .Name("OrdersGrid")
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(o => o.OrderId);
                    columns.Bound(o => o.ShipAddress);
                    columns.Bound(o => o.RequiredDate);
                })
                .Pageable()
                .Sortable();` - I don't see how that is *just wrong* to have in a view.